# Why won't my hover board battery charge?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charger, bms

I have a standard hoverboard battery which I bought for my electric skateboard project.

The battery has a 10s2p arrangement. 36V and 4.4 AH.

Now the battery voltage is 20V.

When I plug my charger in it does not charge and the light is still green. The charger light should turn red to indicate charging.

The charger output is 42V 2A which is the recommended for this battery.

What I think is the pack voltage might be below a certain level and that's why the BMS is not allowing the battery to charge.

Comment: _” What I think is the pack voltage might be below a certain level and that's why BMS not allowing battery to charge”_ That would be my first suspect too and where I would try to manually charge that cell with external means.

Comment: ok will try that

Comment: Put the battery somewhere fireproof if you are going to charge it with an improvised charger.  Lithium batteries do have a habit of catching fire if you charge them wrong, or if the battery is damaged.

Comment: LiPo batteries can become a fire hazard if the get discharges below 3V. Yours seem to be a 2V.